# How to trigger a callback in a Polymer component when it's been attached to the DOM?

Tags: polymer-1.0, jsplumb

I having troules integrating jsPlumb in a Polymer component that is intended to be used as a plugin in an Electron wrapped application. The version of Polymer I'm using is 1.2.0 because that is what was shipped with the the application.

jsPlumb require that the dragable elements and their sources and targets have been mounted to the DOM but that doesn't seem to be the case when  `attached` is fired.

What I did was to set a simeout to keep querying the DOM until the componet's been "truly" mounted, then continue with the initialization passing the new instance of jsPlumb to the nodes in the graph so they can properly set up the sources and targets for each input and output port.

**Question**

What I want to know is whether there is another way to "wait" for the component to be available for jsPlumb using only the Polymer API instead of a timeout?

```
<link rel="import" href="my-node.html">

<dom-module id="my-graph">
    <template>
        <div id="canvas">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nodes}}">
                <my-node></my-node>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-graph",
            properties: {
                nodes: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: function(){return [];}
                }
            },
            attached: function() {
                this._attachedDeferred();
            },
            _attachedDeferred: function() {
                // wait for the component to be attached
                if (!document.contains(this) || !this.offsetParent) {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        this._attachedDeferred();
                    }.bind(this), 100);
                    return;
                }

                // ready to init jsPlumb
                this.instance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
                    Container: "canvas"
                });

                // init the graph nodes
                var nodes = [
                    {
                        pos: [0,0],
                        jsPlumb: this.instance; // the new instance of jsPlumb
                        inputs: {...},
                        outputs: {...}
                    }
                ];
                this.nodes = nodes;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to access the `<my-node>` elements?

`<template is="dom-repeat">` creates it's contents asynchronously, so it's children won't be yet available during `attached`.
You need to listen for the [dom-change](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-change) event before you can access them.

Check out the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#initialization-order) after the "Initialization timing for local DOM children" header.